# How do I invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag in MikTex?

Tags: miktex, shell-escape

I am trying to use the minted package but get the error

```
! Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag.
```

I am using MikTex and have tried going into Edit/Preferences and clicking on PdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex and adding -shell-escape (and also trying --shell-escape) to the arguments but then the compiler does not run at all and I get

```
ERROR: MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
ERROR: Info: 
ERROR: Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Session/SessionImpl.h
ERROR: Line: 640

Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Which editor do you use?

Comment: I linked a **possible duplicate**. Let us know if that is different from your question.

Comment: It is still unclear **which TeX editor** you use or are you configuring the MiKTeX console?

Comment: I am using TeXworks - sorry, I always call this MikTex.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more searching, I found that if I went into Edit/Preferences/typesetting, clicked on PdfLatex+MakeIndex+BibTex and added

```
--tex-option=--shell-escape
```

as the first argument, then it got over this error.

However, now MikTex is telling me

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

I assume it means 'pygments', as I can find nothing on 'pygmentize'. This is most frustrating as pygments **is** installed and I put the folder the distribution is in on the PATH.

I shall have to ask this as a different question!

New question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602580/how-do-i-convince-miktex-that-pygments-is-actually-installed).