# How do I convince MikTex that pygments is actually installed?

Tags: miktex, pygments

*[This is a follow-up question to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602574).]*

I am trying to use the minted package in MikTex to format the Python script. I am getting the error

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

I assume it means 'pygments', as I can find nothing on 'pygmentize'.

However, pygments **is** installed and I put the folder the distribution is in on the PATH. I note that there are only Python files in this folder (no exe files), so perhaps I should be putting something different on the PATH?

The path I am using is

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pygments
```

which has a directory listing

```
 Directory of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pygments

24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          .
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          ..
07/03/2021  19:56            21,538 cmdline.py
07/03/2021  19:56             1,697 console.py
07/03/2021  19:56             1,938 filter.py
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          filters
07/03/2021  19:56             2,893 formatter.py
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          formatters
07/03/2021  19:56            31,477 lexer.py
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          lexers
07/03/2021  19:56               986 modeline.py
07/03/2021  19:56             1,710 plugin.py
07/03/2021  19:56             3,070 regexopt.py
07/03/2021  19:56             3,091 scanner.py
07/03/2021  19:56             4,594 sphinxext.py
07/03/2021  19:56             6,011 style.py
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          styles
07/03/2021  19:56             6,143 token.py
07/03/2021  19:56            63,200 unistring.py
07/03/2021  19:56             9,123 util.py
07/03/2021  19:56             3,012 __init__.py
07/03/2021  19:56               348 __main__.py
24/06/2021  20:26    <DIR>          __pycache__
```

Is this the right directory? If so, how do I get MikTex to pick up on this?

**Update**

Based on the comments I got on this question, I was able to make some progress. I was able to find pygmentize.exe in the directory

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts
```

After adding this to the path, I re-ran MikTex, getting over the

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package.
```

error. Unfortunately, this just opened a new can of worms and I ended up with several `Access denied` errors.

I could continue to pursue this. However, inspired by the comments I got, I opened up the MikTex console (initially looking for the pygmentex package, as suggested below). I didn't find this, but I did find

**pythonhighlight**

This ran first time with no problems, rendering my Python code appropriately (which was the object of the whole exercise). So my advice to anyone else having trouble getting `minted` to work is "don't bother" - use `pythonhighlight` instead!

Comment: Are you sure it's accessible? Does `where pygmentize` give?

Comment: there should be an executable script called pygmentize somewhere, probably not the directory you show which is the underlying python. But I don't know how it installs in windows.

Comment: google suggests it will be in C:\Python33\Scripts

Comment: The package name is pygmentex.  If pygments contains python scritps, it isn't a LaTeX package.

Comment: Thank you for these comments. I shall update my original question with my progress.

Answer (score 0):

You must add TWO folders to your PATH: the one where your executable python is and the one with pygmentize.exe.

In my case I have a portable installation of WinPython in this folder:

```
d:\Roberto\WPy64-31090
```

So I added these two folders to the existing PATH:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;d:\Roberto\WPy64-31090\python-3.10.9.amd64\;d:\Roberto\WPy64-31090\python-3.10.9.amd64\Scripts\;
```

Windows 10 has got a system wide alias for "python" and "python3" that invites you to install Python from the Windows Store. This prevented MikTex from calling the Python executable in the path. I had to search in the control panel and deactivate it. You should be able to access it under Settings - Apps - Apps and features - Manage app execution aliases. Find "python" and "python3" and deactivate them.